# How to return each grouping separately in XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, path

I developed this query in T-SQL:

```
; with prov as (
select  NPI,FileCreationDate, FileCreationTime
from TN_DataFeed2
group by NPI,FileCreationDate, FileCreationTime
)

SELECT   
NPI as [NPI], 
FileCreationDate as [FileCreationDate], 
FileCreationTime as [FileCreationTime],
(

Select  
ProviderPatientNo ,
LastName as [LastName],
FirstName as [FirstName],
SSN as [SSN],
DOB as [DOB],
Gender as [Gender],
Race as [Race],
Ethnicity as [Ethnicity],

(
Select  
t_phone.ProviderPhoneAssessmentId,
t_phone.ProviderF2FAssessmentId,
CallEndDate, 
CallEndTime,
DispatchDate, 
DispatchTime, 
CallDisposition, 
DispositionOther, 
Notes,

(
select   
ProviderF2FAssessmentId,
AssessmentDate, 
[ArrivalTime] ,
ResidentialStatus AS [ResidentialStatus],
County AS [County], 
EmploymentStatus AS [EmploymentStatus], 
MaritalStatus AS [MaritalStatus], 
MilitaryStatus AS [MilitaryStatus],
NumArrests30Days AS [NumArrests30Days], 
AttendedSchoolLast3Months AS [AttendedSchoolLast3Months]

FROM #Assessments t_assess
where t_phone.ProviderPatientNo = t_assess.ProviderPatientNo
and t_assess.ProviderF2FAssessmentId is not null
FOR XML PATH('F2FAssessment'), type) AS [*]

FROM (select distinct ProviderPatientNo, ProviderPhoneAssessmentId,ProviderF2FAssessmentId,CallEndDate,CallEndTime,DispatchDate,DispatchTime, 
CallDisposition,DispositionOther,Notes from #phones where CallDisposition in (1,5,8) 
and ProviderPhoneAssessmentId = t_base.ProviderPhoneAssessmentId) t_phone
FOR XML PATH('PhoneAssessment'), type) AS [*]

FROM (select distinct ProviderPhoneAssessmentId, ProviderPatientNo,LastName,FirstName,SSN,DOB,Gender,Race,Ethnicity  from #base) t_base
FOR XML PATH('Patient'), type
)
from prov
for xml path(''), root('Provider')
```

Which returns data like:

```
  <Patient>
    <ProviderPatientNo>00200791</ProviderPatientNo>
    <LastName>Rob</LastName>
    <FirstName>Chris</FirstName>
    <SSN>7570193</SSN>
    <DOB>2005-09-21</DOB>
    <Gender>2</Gender>
    <Race>6</Race>
    <Ethnicity>2</Ethnicity>
    <PhoneAssessment>
      <ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>0A923156-A8F9-4B92-9FFE-7630B99CBE8D</ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>
      <CallEndDate>2013-09-01</CallEndDate>
      <CallEndTime>13:55:00</CallEndTime>
      <CallDisposition>8</CallDisposition>
      <F2FAssessment>
        <ProviderF2FAssessmentId>BDEC13F5-E175-4A36-A7EA-760DC0E3E786</ProviderF2FAssessmentId>
        <AssessmentDate>2014-01-02</AssessmentDate>
        <ArrivalTime>15:05:00</ArrivalTime>
        <ResidentialStatus>11</ResidentialStatus>
        <County>75</County>
        <EmploymentStatus>10</EmploymentStatus>
        <MaritalStatus>6</MaritalStatus>
        <MilitaryStatus>4</MilitaryStatus>
        <AttendedSchoolLast3Months>1</AttendedSchoolLast3Months>
      </F2FAssessment>
      <F2FAssessment>
        <ProviderF2FAssessmentId>CE0AE86F-1DE3-4B7D-A8FC-B3D07D09B495</ProviderF2FAssessmentId>
        <AssessmentDate>2014-01-02</AssessmentDate>
        <ArrivalTime>13:40:00</ArrivalTime>
        <ResidentialStatus>11</ResidentialStatus>
        <County>97</County>
        <EmploymentStatus>10</EmploymentStatus>
        <MaritalStatus>6</MaritalStatus>
        <MilitaryStatus>4</MilitaryStatus>
        <AttendedSchoolLast3Months>3</AttendedSchoolLast3Months>
      </F2FAssessment>
    </PhoneAssessment>
  </Patient>
```

But instead I want this data to look like:

```
  <Patient>
    <ProviderPatientNo>00200791</ProviderPatientNo>
    <LastName>Rob</LastName>
    <FirstName>Chris</FirstName>
    <SSN>7570193</SSN>
    <DOB>2005-09-21</DOB>
    <Gender>2</Gender>
    <Race>6</Race>
    <Ethnicity>2</Ethnicity>
    <PhoneAssessment>
      <ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>0A923156-A8F9-4B92-9FFE-7630B99CBE8D</ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>
      <CallEndDate>2013-09-01</CallEndDate>
      <CallEndTime>13:55:00</CallEndTime>
      <CallDisposition>8</CallDisposition>
      <F2FAssessment>
        <ProviderF2FAssessmentId>BDEC13F5-E175-4A36-A7EA-760DC0E3E786</ProviderF2FAssessmentId>
        <AssessmentDate>2014-01-02</AssessmentDate>
        <ArrivalTime>15:05:00</ArrivalTime>
        <ResidentialStatus>11</ResidentialStatus>
        <County>75</County>
        <EmploymentStatus>10</EmploymentStatus>
        <MaritalStatus>6</MaritalStatus>
        <MilitaryStatus>4</MilitaryStatus>
        <AttendedSchoolLast3Months>1</AttendedSchoolLast3Months>
      </F2FAssessment>
</PhoneAssessment>
    <PhoneAssessment>
      <ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>0A923156-A8F9-4B92-9FFE-7630B99CBE8D</ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>
      <CallEndDate>2013-09-01</CallEndDate>
      <CallEndTime>13:55:00</CallEndTime>
      <CallDisposition>8</CallDisposition>
      <F2FAssessment>
        <ProviderF2FAssessmentId>CE0AE86F-1DE3-4B7D-A8FC-B3D07D09B495</ProviderF2FAssessmentId>
        <AssessmentDate>2014-01-02</AssessmentDate>
        <ArrivalTime>13:40:00</ArrivalTime>
        <ResidentialStatus>11</ResidentialStatus>
        <County>97</County>
        <EmploymentStatus>10</EmploymentStatus>
        <MaritalStatus>6</MaritalStatus>
        <MilitaryStatus>4</MilitaryStatus>
        <AttendedSchoolLast3Months>3</AttendedSchoolLast3Months>
      </F2FAssessment>
    </PhoneAssessment>
  </Patient>
```

How do I modify my SQL query accordingly?
Also, here is this data from these temp tables.

```
select * from #Assessments where ProviderPatientNo = '00200791'
people_id   ProviderPatientNo   ProviderF2FAssessmentId ProviderPhoneAssessmentId   AssessmentDate  ArrivalTime ResidentialStatus   County  EmploymentStatus    MaritalStatus   MilitaryStatus  NumArrests30Days    AttendedSchoolLast3Months   EducationLevel  PrimaryPayorSource  SecondaryPayorSource    AnnualHouseholdIncome   NumberInHousehold   CurrentServices MHTreatmentDeclaration  MOTStatus   DurablePOA  AssessmentLocation  TransportedByLE TelevideoAssessment CurrentDetoxSymptoms    HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms  PrimaryDSMDiagnosis SecondaryDSMDiagnosis   CompletedByLastName CompletedByFirstName    DateDispositionCompleted    TimeDispositionCompleted    RecommendedTransportMode    DateTransportedToFacility   TimeTransportedToFacility   FollowupContacted   FollowupReportedServiceHelpful  ContactAttempts VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended   AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth    IsAdmitted  FirstHospitalization    PrimaryProblem  IntellectualDisability  MedicalInstability  MedicationIssues    PastTrauma  SubstanceAbuse  RowNumber
9E94386B-BBEE-4E47-BD80-77FA08D9CEA2    00200791    BDEC13F5-E175-4A36-A7EA-760DC0E3E786    NULL    2014-01-02  15:05:00    11  75  10  6   4   NULL    1   23  8   9   NULL    NULL    8   2   2   2   4   0   0   0   0   V71.09  V71.09  Brad    Reb 2013-09-03  11:55:19    NULL    2013-09-03  11:55:19    1   1   1   NULL    NULL    0   1   10  3   3   3   3   3   1
9E94386B-BBEE-4E47-BD80-77FA08D9CEA2    00200791    CE0AE86F-1DE3-4B7D-A8FC-B3D07D09B495    NULL    2014-01-02  13:40:00    11  97  10  6   4   NULL    3   22  8   9   NULL    NULL    8   2   2   2   12  0   0   0   0   V71.09  V71.09  Alex    Phyl    2013-09-23  20:51:13    NULL    2013-09-23  20:51:13    1   1   1   NULL    NULL    0   1   10  3   3   3   3   3   1

select * from #phones where ProviderPatientNo = '00200791'
people_id   ProviderPatientNo   ProviderPhoneAssessmentId   ProviderF2FAssessmentId CallEndDate CallEndTime DispatchDate    DispatchTime    CallDisposition DispositionOther    Notes
9E94386B-BBEE-4E47-BD80-77FA08D9CEA2    00200791    0A923156-A8F9-4B92-9FFE-7630B99CBE8D    NULL    2013-09-01  13:55:00    NULL    NULL    8   NULL    NULL
select * from #base where ProviderPatientNo = '00200791'
NPI FileCreationDate    FileCreationTime    ProviderPatientNo   ProviderF2FAssessmentId ProviderPhoneAssessmentId   people_id   LastName    FirstName   SSN DOB Gender  Race    Ethnicity
1306875695  2014-01-02  14:21:08    00200791    NULL    0A923156-A8F9-4B92-9FFE-7630B99CBE8D    9E94386B-BBEE-4E47-BD80-77FA08D9CEA2    Rob Chris   7570193 2005-09-21  2   6   2
1306875695  2014-01-02  14:21:08    00200791    BDEC13F5-E175-4A36-A7EA-760DC0E3E786    NULL    9E94386B-BBEE-4E47-BD80-77FA08D9CEA2    Rob Chris   7570193 2005-09-21  2   6   2
1306875695  2014-01-02  14:21:08    00200791    CE0AE86F-1DE3-4B7D-A8FC-B3D07D09B495    NULL    9E94386B-BBEE-4E47-BD80-77FA08D9CEA2    Rob Chris   7570193 2005-09-21  2   6   2
```

Comment: Can you help us spot what the **difference** between those two rather large XML documents is? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to add the PhoneAssessment tag in BOTH times instead of grouping by PhoneAssessment.  See updated (shorter) XML code above.

Comment: Hello.  Yes, you probably can still do this with FOR XML PATH - most things can be.  I agree that we really could use some setup help to figure it out very well.  I happen to understand your question pretty quickly myself, but it is awfully tough to play with your query to make the change when I can't run it.  What folks are trying to say is that for such questions, it's best to lead off with CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements in front of the query... make it easy to play with so we can give you something real - and running :) - in return.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the FOR XML EXPLICIT clause.  It allows you to define the hierarchies.  You just have to sort the data correctly.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx

You could also create a xml schema and store the results into a table defined with a column of this type.  This will make sure you output is typed correctly before transferring to another system.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176009.aspx

**Either way, sample tables and data are needed before anyone can help you with your specific example.**

Comment: Which tables do you want to see?  I included sample data in my description.  EXPLICIT is not the solution I'm looking for.  I believe I am really close though, I just want to tweak the FOR XML PATH logic without modifying the schema file.

Comment: See question 20893441, user supplied sample data.  Check out my code to set up a test case in tempdb.  I really hate to create tables and data from scratch ... Especially on something this complex.  Plus you are referencing some local temp tables that are not defined ...

Comment: Crafty, I checked 20893441, but that example is not for FOR XML.  I also added some sample data above.  What I am trying to do should be fairly simple.  Could you please look at what I have?

Answer (score 0):

Like I stated above, the more information you can supply the better.  I do this work on my own time.

Therefore, I am going to have to **force people to post examples** (complete code) like the one below.  Otherwise, I will have to decline to help.  Just setting up the tables and adding data took over an hour.

Here is the code to set up the three tables in tempdb with sample data that you supplied.  I guessed at data types since none were given.  I did not add any referential integrity.

```
-- Playing around
use tempdb
go


--
-- Table 1
--

-- Remove if it exists
if object_id('base') > 0
drop table base
go

-- Create the first table  
create table base
(
    NPI varchar(16),
    FileCreationDate date,
    FileCreationTime time,  
    ProviderPatientNo varchar(16),          
    ProviderF2FAssessmentId uniqueidentifier default null, 
    ProviderPhoneAssessmentId uniqueidentifier default null, 
    people_id uniqueidentifier default null,
    LastName varchar(64),    
    FirstName varchar(64),   
    SSN varchar(9),
    DOB date,
    Gender int,
    Race int,   
    Ethnicity int
);
go

-- Add row 1
insert into base values 
('1306875695',
'2014-01-02',
'14:21:08',
'00200791',
NULL,                   
'0A923156-A8F9-4B92-9FFE-7630B99CBE8D',
'9E94386B-BBEE-4E47-BD80-77FA08D9CEA2',
'Rob',
'Chris',   
'7570193',
'2005-09-21',
2,
6,
2);
go

-- Add row 2
insert into base values 
('1306875695',
'2014-01-02',
'14:21:08',
'00200791',
'BDEC13F5-E175-4A36-A7EA-760DC0E3E786',
NULL,
'9E94386B-BBEE-4E47-BD80-77FA08D9CEA2',
'Rob', 
'Chris',
'7570193', 
'2005-09-21',
2,
6,
2);
go

-- Add row 3
insert into base values 
('1306875695',
'2014-01-02',
'14:21:08',
'00200791',
'CE0AE86F-1DE3-4B7D-A8FC-B3D07D09B495',
NULL,
'9E94386B-BBEE-4E47-BD80-77FA08D9CEA2',
'Rob', 
'Chris',
'7570193', 
'2005-09-21',
2,
6,
2);
go

-- Show the data
select * from base 
where ProviderPatientNo = '00200791';
go


--
-- Table 2
--

-- Remove if it exists
if object_id('phones') > 0
drop table phones
go

-- Create the second table  
create table phones
(
    people_id uniqueidentifier default null,  
    ProviderPatientNo varchar(16),
    ProviderPhoneAssessmentId uniqueidentifier default null,   
    ProviderF2FAssessmentId uniqueidentifier default null, 
    CallEndDate date,
    CallEndTime time,
    DispatchDate date,   
    DispatchTime time,   
    CallDisposition int,
    DispositionOther int,   
    Notes varchar(max)
);
go

-- Add row 1
insert into phones values 
(
'9E94386B-BBEE-4E47-BD80-77FA08D9CEA2',
'00200791',    
'0A923156-A8F9-4B92-9FFE-7630B99CBE8D',   
NULL,  
'2013-09-01',  
'13:55:00',    
NULL,    
NULL,    
8,   
NULL,    
NULL
);
go

-- Show the data
select * from phones 
where ProviderPatientNo = '00200791';
go


--
-- Table 3
--

-- Remove if it exists
if object_id('assessments') > 0
drop table assessments
go

-- Create the third table  
create table assessments
(
    people_id uniqueidentifier default null,
    ProviderPatientNo varchar(16),
    ProviderF2FAssessmentId uniqueidentifier default null,
    ProviderPhoneAssessmentId uniqueidentifier default null,
    AssessmentDate date,
    ArrivalTime time ,
    ResidentialStatus int,
    County int,
    EmploymentStatus int,
    MaritalStatus int,
    MilitaryStatus int,
    NumArrests30Days int,
    AttendedSchoolLast3Months int,
    EducationLevel int,
    PrimaryPayorSource int,
    SecondaryPayorSource int,
    AnnualHouseholdIncome money,
    NumberInHousehold int,
    CurrentServices int ,
    MHTreatmentDeclaration int,
    MOTStatus int,
    DurablePOA int,
    AssessmentLocation int,
    TransportedByLE int,
    TelevideoAssessment int,
    CurrentDetoxSymptoms int,
    HistoryOfDetoxSymptoms int,
    PrimaryDSMDiagnosis varchar(8),
    SecondaryDSMDiagnosis varchar(8),
    CompletedByLastName varchar(64),
    CompletedByFirstName varchar(64),
    DateDispositionCompleted date,
    TimeDispositionCompleted time,
    RecommendedTransportMode int,
    DateTransportedToFacility date,
    TimeTransportedToFacility time,
    FollowupContacted int,
    FollowupReportedServiceHelpful int,
    ContactAttempts int,
    VoluntaryAdmissionRecommended int,
    AdmissionAssessmentViaTelehealth int,
    IsAdmitted int,
    FirstHospitalization int,
    PrimaryProblem int,
    IntellectualDisability int,
    MedicalInstability int,
    MedicationIssues int,
    PastTrauma int,
    SubstanceAbuse int,
    RowNumber int
);


-- Add row 1
insert into assessments values 
(
'9E94386B-BBEE-4E47-BD80-77FA08D9CEA2',
'00200791',
'BDEC13F5-E175-4A36-A7EA-760DC0E3E786',
NULL,
'2014-01-02',
'15:05:00',
11,
75,
10,
6,
4,
NULL,
1,
23,
8,
9,
NULL,
NULL,
8,
2,
2,
2,
4,
0,
0,
0,
0,
'V71.09',
'V71.09',
'Brad',
'Reb',
'2013-09-03',
'11:55:19',
NULL,
'2013-09-03',
'11:55:19',
1,
1,
1,
NULL,
NULL,
0,
1,
10,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3,
1);
go

-- Add row 2
insert into assessments values 
('9E94386B-BBEE-4E47-BD80-77FA08D9CEA2',
'00200791',
'CE0AE86F-1DE3-4B7D-A8FC-B3D07D09B495',
NULL,
'2014-01-02',
'13:40:00',
11,
97,
10,
6,
4,
NULL,
3,
22,
8,
9,
NULL,
NULL,
8,
2,
2,
2,
12,
0,
0,
0,
0,
'V71.09',
'V71.09',
'Alex',
'Phyl',
'2013-09-23',
'20:51:13',
NULL,
'2013-09-23',
'20:51:13',
1,
1,
1,
NULL,
NULL,
0,
1,
10,
3,
3,
3,
3,
3 ,
1);
go

-- Show the data
select * from assessments 
where ProviderPatientNo = '00200791';
go
```

Okay, now we have data, we can talk about a solution.  Here are some observations.

1 - You want to reduce the number of total patient records to 1.

2 - You want to have the same number of phone records as assessments.  Therefore, we need to add (duplicate) some data.

3 - You want one assessment record be inside one phone record.

Again, the solution lends itself to XML Explicit.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx

I choose to do this with a @ProviderPatientNo parameter.  If you want the whole table, change the selects in the FROM clauses in the code below to join back to the base table.

The solution follows:

```
--
-- Explicit = supports simple hierarchies
--

  -- Dump for a particular id
  DECLARE @ProviderPatientNo varchar(16) = '00200791';

  -- Define elemenents @ level 1
  SELECT
      1 AS Tag,
      NULL as Parent,
      NULL as 'Patients!1!element',

      NULL as 'Patient!2!sort!hide',
      NULL as 'Patient!2!ProviderPatientNo!Element',
      NULL as 'Patient!2!LastName!Element',
      NULL as 'Patient!2!FirstName!Element',
      NULL as 'Patient!2!SSN!Element',
      NULL as 'Patient!2!DOB!Element',
      NULL as 'Patient!2!Gender!Element',
      NULL as 'Patient!2!Race!Element',   
      NULL as 'Patient!2!Ethnicity!Element',

      NULL as 'PhoneAssessment!3!ProviderPhoneAssessmentId!Element',
      NULL as 'PhoneAssessment!3!ProviderF2FAssessmentId!Element',
      NULL as 'PhoneAssessment!3!CallEndDate!Element',
      NULL as 'PhoneAssessment!3!CallEndTime!Element',
      NULL as 'PhoneAssessment!3!DispatchDate!Element',
      NULL as 'PhoneAssessment!3!DispatchTime!Element',
      NULL as 'PhoneAssessment!3!CallDisposition!Element',
      NULL as 'PhoneAssessment!3!DispositionOther!Element',
      NULL as 'PhoneAssessment!3!Notes!Element',

      NULL as 'F2FAssessment!4!ProviderF2FAssessmentId!Element',
      NULL as 'F2FAssessment!4!AssessmentDate!Element',
      NULL as 'F2FAssessment!4!ArrivalTime!Element',
      NULL as 'F2FAssessment!4!ResidentialStatus!Element',
      NULL as 'F2FAssessment!4!County!Element',
      NULL as 'F2FAssessment!4!EmploymentStatus!Element',
      NULL as 'F2FAssessment!4!MaritalStatus!Element',
      NULL as 'F2FAssessment!4!MilitaryStatus!Element',
      NULL as 'F2FAssessment!4!NumArrests30Days!Element',
      NULL as 'F2FAssessment!4!AttendedSchoolLast3Months!Element'

  UNION ALL

  -- Patient info @ level 2
  SELECT DISTINCT
      2 as Tag,
      1 as Parent,
      NULL,

      b.ProviderPatientNo + '000' as sort,
      ProviderPatientNo,
      LastName,
      FirstName,
      SSN,
      DOB,
      Gender,
      Race,
      Ethnicity,

      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL, 
      NULL,

      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL
  FROM base b
  WHERE b.ProviderPatientNo = @ProviderPatientNo

  UNION ALL

  -- Phone assement info @ level 3
  SELECT  
      3 as Tag,
      2 as Parent,
      NULL,

      p.ProviderPatientNo + REPLACE( STR( ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 0)), 3, 0), ' ', '0') as sort,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,

      p.ProviderPhoneAssessmentId,
      p.ProviderF2FAssessmentId,
      p.CallEndDate, 
      p.CallEndTime,
      p.DispatchDate, 
      p.DispatchTime, 
      p.CallDisposition, 
      p.DispositionOther, 
      p.Notes,

      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL
  FROM phones p join assessments a 
  ON p.people_id = a.people_id  
  WHERE 
      p.CallDisposition in (1,5,8) and
      p.ProviderPatientNo = @ProviderPatientNo

  UNION ALL

  -- Provider assement info @ level 4
  SELECT  
      4 as Tag,
      3 as Parent,
      NULL,

      a.ProviderPatientNo + REPLACE( STR( ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 0)), 3, 0), ' ', '0') as sort,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,

      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      NULL, 

      a.ProviderF2FAssessmentId,
      a.AssessmentDate, 
      a.ArrivalTime,
      a.ResidentialStatus,
      a.County, 
      a.EmploymentStatus, 
      a.MaritalStatus, 
      a.MilitaryStatus,
      a.NumArrests30Days, 
      a.AttendedSchoolLast3Months
  FROM assessments a join phones p  
  ON a.people_id = p.people_id
  WHERE 
      a.ProviderF2FAssessmentId is not null and
      p.ProviderPatientNo = @ProviderPatientNo

  ORDER BY 'Patient!2!sort!hide' , Tag
  FOR XML EXPLICIT;
```

To recap the solution, you must define the structure in the first select and union in data at each level.

I added a hidden sort column to order the data, this is key to the solution.   Based on patient id and a row number since there is no collation between the phone records expanded to 2 records and the 2 assessments records.

For instance, as level say 4, place null values in all data except level 4's elements.  The tag and parent need to be supplied.

Last but not least, use the FOR XML EXPLICIT to convert the column headings, data, and structure to XML.

As you can see, this is a-lot of work to setup but returns the requested results.

```
<Patients>
  <Patient>
    <ProviderPatientNo>00200791</ProviderPatientNo>
    <LastName>Rob</LastName>
    <FirstName>Chris</FirstName>
    <SSN>7570193</SSN>
    <DOB>2005-09-21</DOB>
    <Gender>2</Gender>
    <Race>6</Race>
    <Ethnicity>2</Ethnicity>
    <PhoneAssessment>
      <ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>0A923156-A8F9-4B92-9FFE-7630B99CBE8D</ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>
      <CallEndDate>2013-09-01</CallEndDate>
      <CallEndTime>13:55:00</CallEndTime>
      <CallDisposition>8</CallDisposition>
      <F2FAssessment>
        <ProviderF2FAssessmentId>BDEC13F5-E175-4A36-A7EA-760DC0E3E786</ProviderF2FAssessmentId>
        <AssessmentDate>2014-01-02</AssessmentDate>
        <ArrivalTime>15:05:00</ArrivalTime>
        <ResidentialStatus>11</ResidentialStatus>
        <County>75</County>
        <EmploymentStatus>10</EmploymentStatus>
        <MaritalStatus>6</MaritalStatus>
        <MilitaryStatus>4</MilitaryStatus>
        <AttendedSchoolLast3Months>1</AttendedSchoolLast3Months>
      </F2FAssessment>
    </PhoneAssessment>
    <PhoneAssessment>
      <ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>0A923156-A8F9-4B92-9FFE-7630B99CBE8D</ProviderPhoneAssessmentId>
      <CallEndDate>2013-09-01</CallEndDate>
      <CallEndTime>13:55:00</CallEndTime>
      <CallDisposition>8</CallDisposition>
      <F2FAssessment>
        <ProviderF2FAssessmentId>CE0AE86F-1DE3-4B7D-A8FC-B3D07D09B495</ProviderF2FAssessmentId>
        <AssessmentDate>2014-01-02</AssessmentDate>
        <ArrivalTime>13:40:00</ArrivalTime>
        <ResidentialStatus>11</ResidentialStatus>
        <County>97</County>
        <EmploymentStatus>10</EmploymentStatus>
        <MaritalStatus>6</MaritalStatus>
        <MilitaryStatus>4</MilitaryStatus>
        <AttendedSchoolLast3Months>3</AttendedSchoolLast3Months>
      </F2FAssessment>
    </PhoneAssessment>
  </Patient>
</Patients>
```